# Is there any command in R which will give me date in format DD-MM-YY?

Tags: r

I want the date to be in format `DD-MM-YY` ie `01-08-2019`

I have tried the following, but this code is not giving me the result in this format:

```
as.Date("1-08-2019",format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is changing your string to a date. The `format =` argument is letting the function know the existing format of your string if it was a date, i.e. with the day first, then month, then year (which is different to the standard date format of year - month - day in R).

You then need to format it to change the order using `format()`.

```
date_to_change <- as.Date("1-08-2019", format = '%d-%m-%Y')
format(date_to_change, '%d-%m-%Y')
[1] "01-08-2019"
```

However, this is a character string again. So that works if that is how you want to present it, but if you want to work with it as a date object, you have to leave it in the format you get when you use `as.Date()`.

Comment: I also tried this but I am not able to apply operation on the variables in which i stored this.

Comment: start_date<-format(as.Date("2019-08-01"),'%d-%m-%Y'),
end_date<-format(as.Date("2019-08-31"),'%d-%m-%Y'),
adv_period<-as.numeric(difftime(end_date,start_date)) , the answer produced here is 10957 days but i want 30 days.

Comment: That's because if you are using them as dates, you need to work with them as date objects rather than formatting them to look how you like. `start_date <-as.Date("2019-08-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2019-08-31") 
adv_period <-as.numeric(difftime(end_date, start_date))`

Comment: The above gives you the answer 30. If you need to display the dates somewhere and you want them in your preferred format, you can change them after you've finished working with them.